# Hibernate stalling when attempting to executing JPA query on Sybase

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I want to perform the following select using JPA:

```
select * from permissions_table where permissions.role in ("Role1", "Role2")
```

What I have so far looks like this:

```
     protected Set<String> getPermissions(Connection conn, String username, Collection<String> roleNames) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            Set<String> permissions = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            try {                                                                        

                 EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();                                
                 CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
                 CriteriaQuery<HierarchicalPermission> criteria = builder.createQuery( HierarchicalPermission.class );
                 Root<HierarchicalPermission> permission = criteria.from(HierarchicalPermission.class);
                 criteria.select(permission).where(permission.get("Role").in(roleNames));
                 List<HierarchicalPermission> hPermissions = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
                 for ( HierarchicalPermission p : hPermissions ) {
                     System.out.println( "Permission (" + p.getRole() +")");
                 }

 }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println( ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }

        return permissions;
    }
```

When I step over this line:

```
List<HierarchicalPermission> hPermissions = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

I see the following in my Eclipse output window:

```
Hibernate: select hierarchic0_.iIdentity as iIdentity0_, hierarchic0_.timestamp as timestamp0_, hierarchic0_.szRole as szRole0_, hierarchic0_.szDescription as szDescri4_0_, hierarchic0_.iResource as iResource0_ from occ.ROLE_PERMISSIONS hierarchic0_ where hierarchic0_.szRole in (?)
```

and Eclipse debugger appears to stall.  At this point, I can only pause or stop execution as shown in this screen shot.

[image]

What is this supposed to mean?  Is this not a valid representation of the above query?

Comment: So, is it an eclipse debugger problem? What happens whenyou execute it using a Run configuration rather than using a Debug configuration?

Comment: Same effect. I see "Hibernate: select hierarchic0_.iIdentity as iIdentity0_, hierarchic0_.timestamp as timestamp0_, hierarchic0_.szRole as szRole0_, hierarchic0_.szDescription as szDescri4_0_, hierarchic0_.iResource as iResource0_ from occ.ROLE_PERMISSIONS hierarchic0_ where hierarchic0_.szRole in (?)" in Output window and execution seems to have stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Database was locked by Sybase Interactive SQL on another machine so Hibernate was stalling while attempting to execute query.  One would think that Hibernate would throw some sort of exception instead of simply stalling when it encounters resource contention but I guess this is not the case.